# Keep cmd.exe command history between sessions?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to keep the cmd command history between sessions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Switch to using PowerShell, and follow the instructions at the following site to enable history:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/perserving-command-history-across-sessions/ ([archived](https://archive.ph/UM9h8))

Alternatively, in cmd.exe, you can use "doskey /history" at the end of your session to show what you typed in that session, but theres no way to really load it into the next session.

Comment: I hestitated to +1 this because "Switch to using PowerShell" is not necessarily as easy as it sounds depending on what sort of stuff you're using the console for, but the info is accurate soooooooooo ;)

Comment: Agreed. I hesitated to put it down but it's the only real answer I can find. I tried to get something similar going on a workstation I had before, but there just isn't a persistent history mechanism available for cmd.exe :-(

Comment: Note that this will keep a list of commands you typed, but it doe *NOT* alter the list of commands that will come up when you hit the up key on the keyboard. It doesn't affect the "doskey" functionality, in other words.

Comment: Should be noted that some commands that work in cmd don't work the same in PowerShell e.g.  mvn install `-Dmaven.test.skip=true would requires a backtick as shown before the dash

Comment: The question is cmd not PowerShell. You shuld start to answer the question and then follow up with alternatives.

Comment: Yes, powershell is not a great option if, like me, you are constantly on different servers, which may or may not have powershell correctly installed or updated and on which I may or may not have install rights.  cmd is always there and always works right away.  However, you may have just convinced me to embrace PS anyway :)

Answer (score 92):

I've found 2 ways, neither of which require switching to PowerShell.

1. Install [Clink](https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/), which enhances `cmd.exe` with persistent history and much more. Just install it and then open `cmd` as normal.
2. Install [TCC/LE](https://jpsoft.com/products/tcc-le.html) free version, which is a separate program, again providing an enhanced version of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I am a bit apprehensive against system-wide replacing  of `cmd.exe` but its a good answer, and clink supports an injection mode as well.

Comment: If you don't want to install it system wide, you can launch it via a shortcut to `clink.bat`.

Comment: On my German Windows, some keyboard shortcuts in the `cmd` window did not work anymore after installing CLink.

Comment: Clink is brilliant. Replaced `cmd` with it, been no problems, very happy with it.

Comment: @LoSauer, Use the portable version. `clink inject`. It only affects the current session.

Comment: @sparrowt, Is there a free version of TCC/LE that last more then 30 days?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Because this is what asked by the question..!! This is best rather than using any other alternative application.

Comment: It is available in Chocolatey!!!!

Comment: Thank you for this. Clink is fantastic and works seamlessly with ConEmu.

Comment: Clink is excellent. It took me a short while to setup a couple of useful shortcuts.

Comment: Holy goodness Clink is awesome! Nice find.  Also, works with JetBrains IDE's embedded command window

Comment: @Pacerier : Sure.  TCC/LE is not limited to 30 days.  My guess is that you downloaded one of the other TC-related demos.  Make sure you chose "TCC/LE".  (Although, at the time of this writing, TCC/LE has fallen behind some of the other TC releases.)

Comment: I used TCC/LE back in the day - I never encountered any incompatibilites between it and the Windows command prompt;

Answer (score 17):

Saving history is a small workflow - here's a less "heavy" way to do this (no external libs).

Create a bat/cmd file to set up your history, in this case I called it MyEnvironment.cmd:

```
doskey save=doskey /history $g$g C:\CmdHistory.log
doskey quit=doskey /history $g$g C:\CmdHistory.log $T exit
doskey history=find /I "$*" C:\CmdHistory.log
cls
```

Then run this from "Start->Run" (you can also setup an alias for this too):

```
cmd.exe /K C:\MyEnvironment.cmd
```

Every time I'm closing a session I hit "quit" - or if I'm afraid of losing history mid-session I hit "save". If I want to grep for something in history, I just hit "history KEYWORD".

---

Per @dave_thompson_085 's comment, the `AutoRun` feature works well if you don't want to use the `/K` switch. If you set up the Registry key correctly, the `.cmd` or `.bat` does not need to be in `%AppData%`, it can be in the same location it already is.

If you do use the `%AppData%` location, be aware that cmd will probably look for your batch file in the "Roaming" folder (instead of the AppData root).

More info on the `AutoRun` CMD feature: https://superuser.com/a/302553/333316

**Update (Oct. 2020) on Autorun**: I've used this feature now for years, but would like to point out many programs that rely on CMD to run background commands (Visual Studio, Win32 apps), get **very** confused if anything runs before the passed CMD command (e.g. VS developer prompt). If this causes pain, switch to the `/K` method.

Comment: What `$g` and `$t` are for?

Comment: @Chinggis6 `$g` inserts a `>`, and `$t` is a command separator.

Comment: @Superole ah ok, **g**reater than and **t**erminate, but why not to use `>` and `&&` characters directly in the doskey alias?

Comment: @Chinggis6 because that would break the command creating the alias. Then the command-interpreter would assume that you meant: first execute `doskey quit=doskey /history` and save the output of the macro creation in a logfile (either nothing or an errormessage); next close the window (discarding everything). -You could escape those characters with a `^` instead though, I think. Like `^>^>` and `^&` (...and yes, you only need one ampersand)

Comment: Instead of explicit `/k` can use `AutoRun` https://superuser.com/a/302553/333316

Comment: As of [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10), apparently [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) is an option, [InfoWorld: ...Bash on Windows](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3178631/discover-the-power-of-bash-on-windows.html). I haven't bothered to configure and use it though.

Answer (score 3):

I use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). It also provides some others functionalities that Linux has but Windows not.

Answer (score 0):

My solution may qualify as worse than a hack—perhaps even cheating.

I save the history of my session's commands into a file, say,

```
doskey /h > mysession.txt
```

Then, in the next session, I open `mysession.txt` with the text editor, copy the command I am interested in, and paste it into the `cmd`/`shell` session, and execute it directly.

Downvotes are rightly deserved `^_^`.