# Determining wget arguments used, by file and output analysis

Tags: command-line, wget

The title says almost all. I sometimes use wget to create seamless backups of certain webpages (for offline viewing and most importantly, to preserve them in case they go away).

However, I have some habits, and one of them is to write pretty big lines of arguments, as to tell wget how to do everything just right, and to try and preserve resources / avoid 404 returns. Due to my understanding of wget at the time, I usually ended up with some cut backups, which is one of the reasons why this is important.

I have backuped a site that recently had a minor change, that I would like to reget, with all previous arguments. I have all the files (e.g. I mirror-ed it) and I have made a logfile in the process. With these resources is it possible to discern most or all of the arguments used?

For reference, I'm using [Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) although I'm assuming that, if a solution exists, it will be universal.

Comment: hmm. One way to handle this intelligently for the future might be to [enable global history in the command line processor](http://superuser.com/questions/257855/keep-cmd-exe-command-history-between-sessions), and search there. Its too late for now, though

Comment: Was looking for that quite recently, but I'm not moving to PowerShell for now. Thanks though.