# Is it Possible to get list of commands i typed in dos prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, history

I would like to search my own CMD history. we could browse within the same session, you can browse it with the up and down arrow keys but what about the history of former CMD sessions? 
Is there a file, a log the history gets written to ?if so is it there any way to find the history file?

in linux we could get bash history,is it there any similar way to get cmd history?

Note : i wish to view the command history even after the system shutdown ,but the duplicated [question](https://superuser.com/questions/257855/keep-cmd-exe-command-history-between-sessions) was related to keeping session history

Comment: @karel its about keeping session ,but this one is about keeping **overall history file even after restart**

Comment: The Windows PowerShell script in the accepted answer to  the linked question puts a file in your profile that defines a function BYE which saves from your session's history into a History.csv file in your home directory and then adds that to your history when you start the next session. The saved History.csv file is persistent after restarts. You also get to control how much of the history you want to keep.